# How to write custom "textChanged" function in c#?

Tags: c#, function, textchanged

This is a code for a single textbox textChanged function. But I want to write a code for common textChanged. I have many textbox named like tbL1InterSR, tbL2InterSR........tbL10InterSR.

```
private void tbL1InterSR_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbHOI.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            if (tbL1InterSR.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                tbL1RL.Text = (Convert.ToSingle(tbHOI.Text) - Convert.ToSingle(tbL1InterSR.Text)).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

I just want to write a common textChanged function.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One Event for all TextBoxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926160/one-event-for-all-textboxes)

Comment: You can refactor your method's body to another public static method that can be accessed anywhere. Something likes `public static void DoSomething(TextBox tbL1RL, TextBox tbHOI, TextBox tbL1InterSR)`, or you can try Extension method too.

Comment: @Glubus , This function is specific for "tbL1InterSR" textbox, But I want it as a common. means for any textbox I just add this function on textChanged then it works properly.

Comment: @Jesses Good. I want the specific code refer to my given code in question body.

Comment: Well just create a single event handler, and then register all your textboxes to it. You can get all your textboxes by getting them manually, using reflection, or by using the controls list (if you're using the right library).

Comment: Do you have two accounts, rakib? Either way it's exactly the same principle as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383670/how-to-write-common-function-for-keypress-function-check-for-floating-number-of/36386023#36386023 -- Just keep overriding the events you want in the same TextBox.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your question correctly... 
You could simply call the same handler for all textboxes changed event.

Also you know who called the function from the sender argument.  That way you know which textbox you're dealing with.

Its simple as calling the same function from two different places.

```
private void TxtBoxChanged(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender; // < -- this how u know which txtBox u working with..
    // more code.....
}
```